# Export all tables from a database into CSV format using python

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pyodbc

```
import pandas as pd

import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'

                      'Server=DESKTOP-0LA566U\SQLEXPRESS;'

                      'Database=AdventureWorksDW2019;'

                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

                

database=['DatabaseLog', 'DimAccount']

cursor = conn.cursor()

for i in database:

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM database')

print(I)

    

df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)

df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\cdtpr\OneDrive\Desktop\connections\database.csv', index = False)
```

[getting error as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy1D9.jpg)

```
PS C:\Users\cdtpr\OneDrive\Desktop\connections> & C:/Users/cdtpr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python

.exe "c:/Users/cdtpr/OneDrive/Desktop/connections/import pandas as pd.py"

now

45 mins

Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\cdtpr\OneDrive\Desktop\connections\import pandas as pd.py", line 14, in <module> cursor.execute('SELECT FROM database')

55 mins

57 mins

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax r the keyword 'database'. (156) (SQLExecDirect)") nea

59 mins

PS C:\Users\cdtpr\OneDrive\Desktop\connections>
```

Comment: What do you think `SELECT * FROM DATABASE` will do..? That error (*"Incorrect syntax r the keyword 'database'"*) isn't valid either, it appears to contain typographic errors

Answer (score 1):

First load a DataFrame with this query

`select schema_name(schema_id) schema_name, name table_name from sys.tables`

Then iterate over the rows in that constructing a query like

`sql = f"select * from [{schemaName}].[{tableName}]"`

for each table.

Comment: Hi David I tried it but it is not working can you write the code. I have sent you the request on LinkedIn pls accept my request ASAP.

Comment: My New Code


import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-0LA566U\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=AdventureWorksDW2019;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
                

database=['DatabaseLog', 'DimAccount']
for i in database:
  sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''
                                select * from ''',database
                              ,conn) 
  print(I)


    
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\path_name\database.csv', index = False)

Comment: Update your code in your question, not a comment, and if you're getting an error, add that too.  SO is not a code writing service.